# Remove /public from URL in a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a Laravel application, and it will be in a subfolder of a current project. I'm trying to get rid of the /public in the URL, so that the users can view the project at this URL :

```
www.domain.com/project
```

instead of the default ...

```
www.domain.com/project/public
```

I did some digging on StackOverflow and the Laracasts forum, and I tried this, in a `.htaccess` file at the root of my project :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, my routes doesn't work anymore when I do this. Even the default route for `/` stopped working.

A lot of answers mention that the best way is to change the root in the Apache config, so that it serves the files from /public instead of at the root of the directory.

The problem is that this in a subfolder of a main project, how can I make it so that only this project is affected? The website at `www.domain.com` works fine and does not have a /public in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options.  I don't think you want to try fixing this at the htaccess level with mod rewrites (or anything like that)

One option is to create another virtual host that listens on an abitrary port (eg, 8080).  Then set the document root for this virtual host to .../public/

Another option, you can spoof the dns in your /etc/hosts or Windows hosts file, and set up a dev.domain.com virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

•Go to mainproject/public>>

```
a.  .htacess
b.  favicon.ico
c.  index.php
d.  robots.txt
e.  web.config
```

1.cut these 5 files from public folder,and then paste on the main project folder that’s means out side of public folder… mainproject/files

2.Next after paste ,open index.php ,modify

```
•require __DIR__.'/…/bootstrap/autoload.php';  to

•require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

modify



 - $app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; to


 - $app = require_once DIR.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```